# CRM 2011: What is the correct ServerUrl registry setting after adding a host header and single IIS binding?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Can someone please help me understand what the ServerUrl registry setting is for and what the correct setting should be based on my settings below?

I was under the assumption the ServerUrl registry setting should be set to (http://myservername:80/MSCRMServices) for instances when there would be a need to target a specific server, but since having multiple bindings in the CRM site is not supported and could cause problems with service endpoints, it looks like the only option for me is to set this to (http://crmdev.domain.com:80/MSCRMServices).

Should I be able to set the ServerUrl registry setting to (http://myservername:80/MSCRMServices) without needing a second binding in IIS?

Are there any negative consequences when the ServerUrl registry setting is (http://crmdev.domain.com:80/MSCRMServices) while running multiple network load balanced servers?

**NOTE:** This is an On-Premise installation.

Here are my current settings.

**Registry Settings**

```
Registry subkey: MSCRM  
LocalSdkPort: 80  
ServerUrl: (http://crmdev.domain.com:80/MSCRMServices)
```

**Added a DNS (A) Record**

```
Name: crmdev  
Type: Host (A)  
Data: 192.168.211.18  
Timestamp: static
```

**Microsoft Dynamics CRM (Site Bindings)**

```
Type: http  
Host Name: crmdev.domain.com  
Port: 80  
IP Address: All Unassigned
```

**Deployment Manager (Web Address settings)**

```
Binding Type: HTTP  
Web Application Server: crmdev.domain.com:80  
Organization Web Service: crmdev.domain.com:80  
Discovery Web Service: crmdev.domain.com:80  
Deployment Web Service: crmdev.domain.com:80
```

**SQL Database Settings**
Database: MSCRM_CONFIG
Table: dbo.DeploymentProperties

```
ADDeploymentSdkRootDomain: crmdev.domain.com:80  
ADDiscoveryRootDomain: crmdev.domain.com:80  
ADsdkRootDomain: crmdev.domain.com:80   
ADWebApplicationRootDomain: crmdev.domain.com:80  
AsyncSdkRootDomain:
```